# How to add data into a dictionary from two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
teams = [ India, Australia, England ]
ratings = [ 12, 16, 11 ]
```

I want a dictionary like this

```
dict = { 'India':12, 'Australia':16, 'England':11}
```

I was trying to get it through looping elements of the first list, but I can't add two counters.

```
len1 = len(teams)
for x in range(1, len1):
    dict1[x] = rating
    print dict1
```

How do I create this dictionary?

Comment: `dict(zip(teams, ratings))` will do the trick.

Comment: d = {k:v for k,v in zip(teams, ratings)}

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict` with `zip`

**Ex:**

```
teams = [ 'India', 'Australia', 'England' ]
ratings = [ 12, 16, 11 ]
print(dict(zip(teams, ratings)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'England': 11, 'Australia': 16, 'India': 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your original code, one counter is enough. But lists are zero indexed

```
for x in range(len1):
    dict1[teams[x]] = ratings[x]
```